# How to access specific cell in UICollectionView in willDisplay cell callback

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview, uicollectionview

EDIT: Big picture: I am trying to build a timeline like so: [image] Each cell in the timeline represents a month so May is the last cell in the horizontal collectionView. What I want is when the collectionView loads, it auto-scrolls over to may if its not already visible then calls a specific function on the cell to draw the arrow. The code that I am using to try to do that is below.

Here is my code:

```
var onceOnlyCollectionView = false
var onceOnlyTimeline = false
internal func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, willDisplay cell: UICollectionViewCell, forItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    if collectionView == self.collectionView {
        if !onceOnlyCollectionView {
            let indexToScrollTo = IndexPath(row: self.posts.count - 1, section: 0)
            collectionView.scrollToItem(at: indexToScrollTo, at: .left, animated: false)
            onceOnlyCollectionView = true
        }
    } else if collectionView == self.timeline {
        if !onceOnlyTimeline {
            let firstPost = posts.first?.timeStamp
            let firstOfFirstMonth = firstPost?.startOfMonth()
            let diff = posts.last?.timeStamp.months(from: firstOfFirstMonth!)
            //self.currentPostMonth = diff
            let monthCellIndexPath = IndexPath(row: diff!, section: 0)
            timeline.scrollToItem(at: monthCellIndexPath, at: .centeredHorizontally, animated: false)
            let months = self.posts.first?.timeStamp.startOfMonth().months(from: (self.posts.last?.timeStamp)!)
            print("cells are",self.timeline.visibleCells)
            if let optionalCell = timeline.cellForItem(at: IndexPath(row: months!, section: 0)) {
                let cell = optionalCell as! TimelineMonthViewCell
                let day = Calendar.current.component(.day, from: self.currentPostDate!)
                cell.drawArrow(day: day)
            } else {
                print("cell out of range")
            }
            onceOnlyTimeline = true
        }
    }
}
```

Right now, it does successfully scroll over to may, however it prints "cells are []" and "cell out of range" and does not draw the red arrow.   What is going on here and how do I access this newly-scrolled to cell?

Comment: "I am trying to call it before it loads." What does that mean? Maybe you should explain what you're trying to do at a high level rather than asking for help with a particular solution?

Comment: @DuncanC I heavily edited the question to include the bigger picture. let me know if this is what you were thinking or if I should add more

Comment: Using scrollToItem in your `willDisplay()` method seems like a bad idea.  I've actually never used `collectionView(_:willDisplay:forItemAt:)`, but from the docs, it sounds like that method gets called when a cell has been created but before it gets added to the collection view. Thus it's perfectly reasonable that it would get called when no cells are on-screen yet. It will be called repeatedly as cells are created and added to the collection view. Trying to scroll inside that method is bound to cause problems. Instead you should call scrollToItem() in your viewDidLoad method.

Comment: ok I put the code in viewDidLoad instead but its still not finding those cells hmmm

Answer (score 0):

You can access to specific cell of Collection View simple like this

```
override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, willDisplay cell: UICollectionViewCell, forItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

        if let cell = cell as? MyListingsCollectionViewCell {
            if isStuffAdded {
                //do something you want
            }
        }

}
```